# How could I make this set of code save the user input into another folder?

Tags: c#, save, user-input

I am so lost.... how could I make this set of code save the user input into another folder? (Im trying to save .png files if you need to know that)

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     Stream myStream ;
     SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

     saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"  ;
     saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 ;
     saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;

     if(saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         if((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
         {
             myStream.Close();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: The SaveFileDialog does not do the actual saving for you you need to write some code as well I will post a very simple example for you to try

Comment: Just store the info to a variable and then write to a file/folder that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also some other and or additional code that you would really need to write for example if the user selects a file from one folder, then you could just capture that FilePath using System.IO and look up how to use GetFilePath , FileName, etc... then once the file is selected that they want to save ..why not use the File.Copy() method. there are plenty of additional examples online here on `SO` as well

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using( Stream myStream  = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
    using( StreamWriter sw = new TextWriter(myStream) )
    {
        sw.Write("here you can write lines from a file that you read or you can simple write what ever text you are wanting to save to a file this should help you get started" );
    }
}
```

> Here is an even simpler way of doing it

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.File.Copy(saveFileDialog1.Filename, "some dest filePath");
}
```